# What delimiter to use in FOR loop for reading lines?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a txt file that contains the following lines

```
jfo3 93jfl
lvls 29fdj
nskd jfuwe
xlkw eklwe
```

I'm trying to read the file line by line, and do something with it. What delimiter should I use?

The delim I'm using here reads each word separately.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%x in (lines.txt) do (
    echo %%x
)
```

Answer (score 13):

This reads line by line for me:

```
for /f "delims=" %x in (lines.txt) do echo %x
```

Comment: @sameold: In a batch file you need to use `%%` instead of `%`. The variant in this answer is for use on the command line directly.

Comment: @Joey is correct. The script above works on the command line.

Comment: Why is `"delims="` used for newline delimeter?  Answer: it sets the value of `delims` to empty, meaning the loop uses no character (except newline) as a delimiter

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to delims, but to tokens:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (lines.txt) do echo %%x
```

Comment: Not really, as "tokens=*" and "delims=" produce nearly the same result. As with "tokens=*" the delims are still active, they remove leading spaces and TABs from each line

Comment: if you don't specify `"delims="`, then it will default to `"delims= "` (a space), and it will trim extra whitespace between the tokens which means you are not getting the real lines. `"delims="` by itself will have a default of `"tokens=1"`, but since it grabs the whole line, you only need the one token.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your input file:

> abc,def
>
> ghi,jkl
>
> mno,pqr

then use

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%i in (test.txt) do (whatever u want)
```