# New line as a delimeter of FOR loop

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd, window, delimiter

I am new to batch script, and I am trying to parse a file that has key value (kind) of pairs delimited by new line. For example:

```
the value of abc
1234
the value of def
5678
the value of ghi
9876
```

I would like to read this file using new line as delimited so that I can access the values.

Something like

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims='\n'" %%i in ('findstr /C:the value of abc 'filepath') do echo %%j
```

Comment: Which do you want? Batch or powershell? They are two separate languages. Do you want all lines parsed or just a part of the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bat script, what delim to use to to read text file line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721989/bat-script-what-delim-to-use-to-to-read-text-file-line-by-line)

Answer (score 5):

I just put it here as an option:

```
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%i in ('findstr /C:the value of abc 'filepath') do echo %%i
```

Comment: At least for what I was doing, `delims^=^ eol^=` worked perfectly, can't say I understand what it means though!

Answer (score 3):

You can't set 'new line' as delimiter. Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /NC:"the value of abc" "filepath"') do set /a count=%%i
if defined count for /f "skip=%count%tokens=1*delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /N "^" "filepath"') do if not defined value set "value=%%j"
echo.%value%
endlocal
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "prevline="
FOR /f "delims=" %%z IN (tvabc.txt) DO (
 IF DEFINED prevline (
  FOR /f "tokens=1-6" %%a IN ('echo %%prevline%% %%z') DO (
   ECHO %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f
   )
  SET "prevline="
  ) ELSE (SET prevline=%%z)
)
```

should do the job, if you require each token from two successive lines to be output. Would be much easier if we had a listing of the required output rather than having to guess from code that doesn't work.

Essentially, this code saves the contents of one line then detects that the second has been read by the fact that the variable holding the previous line is defined. Under those circumstances, `for/f` is used to tokenise the concatenation of the two lines.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're going to do with those Name/Value pairs after you get them, but if you're going to do it in Powershell, do it right and start by creating objects:

```
$file = 'c:\somedir\somefile.txt'

[regex]$regex = @'
(?ms)the value of (\S+)
(\d+)
'@

#Choose one
$text = Get-Content $file -Raw  # V3 Only
$text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($file)  # V2 or V3


$regex.matches($text) |
foreach {
   New-object PSObject -Property @{
                                   Name = $_.groups[1].value
                                   Value = $_.groups[2].value
                                  }
        }|
  Select Name,Value |
  Format-Table -AutoSize

Name Value
---- -----
abc  1234 
def  5678 
ghi  9876
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally use the given batch command, to read each line in file

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (test.txt) DO (
    ECHO %%G
)
```

Here, `"delim="` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of that? In powershell:

```
(get-content .\essai.txt)[(Select-String .\essai.txt -Pattern "the value of abc").LineNumber]
```

It displays the next line after the pattern.

Comment: It's not batch script (as stated in question), it's PowerShell.