# new line as delimiter in for loop batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want to print the policy name which is "My Default Policy". I am using the following command, however, this print only "My" as my delimiter is a space. How do i make a new line as the delimiter?

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\McAfee\DLP\Agent\Properties\Policy" | find "PolicyName" > tmp.txt
for /F "tokens=3 delims= " %%f in (tmp.txt) do (echo "Policy Name:" %%f >> C:\mcafee.txt)
```

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6471) will help you. And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641301/new-line-as-a-delimeter-of-for-loop) too. (possible duplicate?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create a temporary file. Read [`FOR /F` - Loop through the output of a command](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html):

```
for /F "tokens=2,*" %%f in ('
    reg query "HKLM\Software\McAfee\DLP\Agent\Properties\Policy" ^| find /I "PolicyName"
  ') do (echo "Policy Name:" %%g >> C:\mcafee.txt)
```

Here

- `tokens=2,*` will process the second token and the 3rd + all subsequent items; this can also be written as `tokens=2*`;
- `delims` is omitted to accept all default delimiters: read [Syntax: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html).

Comment: What does the **%%g** do?

Comment: @luisdev read the section in  [_Tokens_  paragraph](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).